# string to a LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, windows, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ std::string conversion problem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874433/c-stdstring-conversion-problem-on-windows)
>   [How to convert std::string to LPCSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr)

I want to rename a window ( WM_SETTEXT ) to something else. In have a std::string that contains the new window name. I need to convert the std::string to "LPCTSTR", this is becouse SendMessage needs the name in "LPCTSTR".

I can't get this to work, Could some one help me to convert a string to a LPCTSTR?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ std::string conversion problem on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874433/c-stdstring-conversion-problem-on-windows), or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr, or possibly quite a few of the other "Related" questions on this page.

Comment: Is your program compiled in Unicode or ANSI mode? That affects what `LPCTSTR` really is.

Comment: Using SetWindowTextA() is the quick fix.

Comment: Oh @Hans, don't encourage the evil of ANSI text!  ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `c_str()` method of `std::string`. This returns a C string, i.e. a pointer to a null-terminated character array.

```
SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)str.c_str());
```

This is fine if you are compiling for ANSI. If you are compiling for Unicode then you should use `wstring` instead of `string`. If that's the case, just change to `wstring` and the call to `SendMessage` works exactly as written above.

Comment: If I do that, then my window gets a strange name "?????_|"

Comment: That's because you have a mismatch between ANSI and Unicode. If you target Unicode, use `wstring`. If you use ANSI, use `string`. I strongly urge you not to use ANSI in 2012. Build your app for Unicode and use `wstring`. Don't bother with `TCHAR` at all, it just confuses for no discernible gain, in my view.